# Is there a way to use the CLI to copy data from a presigned URL to my own bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a presigned URL for a file in a vendor's S3 bucket. I want to copy that file into my own bucket. I'd rather not copy it to the machine I'm running the copy from. My thought was to use the CLI `s3 sync` or `cp` commands to copy the file from one bucket to another. But those commands require `s3://` URLs, not `https://`.

I tried converting the HTTP URL by replacing "https://bucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com" with "s3://bucketname", but that gives an Access Denied error with `s3 sync` and a Bad Request with `s3 cp`. Is there any way to do this, or do I need to download it locally with HTTP, then upload to my bucket with the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you need to authenticate into two different accounts, the source to read and the destination to write. If you had access to both, i.e. the credentials you use to read could also write to your own bucket, you would be able to bypass the middle-man.

That's not the case here, so your best bet is to download it first, then authenticate with your own account and put the object there.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 has an in-built `CopyObject` command that can read from an S3 bucket and write to an S3 bucket without needing to download the data. To use this command, you require credentials that have `GetObject` permission on the source bucket and `PutObject` permissions on the destination bucket. The credentials themselves can be issued by either the AWS Account having the source bucket or the AWS Account having the destination bucket. Thus, you would need to work with the account admins who control the 'other' AWS Account.

If this is too difficult and your only way of accessing the source object is via a pre-signed URL, then you *cannot* use the `CopyObject` command. Instead, you would need to download the source file and then separately upload it to Amazon S3.